# c# string question

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression, split string by capital letter but ignore TLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097901/regular-expression-split-string-by-capital-letter-but-ignore-tla)

hello everyone,
in c# if i have a string that is a sentence that contain upper case Letters
how can i split the words?

for example:

```
string a = "HelloWorld"
```

and i need

```
b[0] = "Hello";
b[1]= "world";
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097901/regular-expression-split-string-by-capital-letter-but-ignore-tla

Comment: "World" or "world"? if "world" then use str.ToLower();

Comment: Hey buddies, why did you close the question? These are not the same Question.

Comment: Here are two more solutions by LINQ. IEnumerable<string> enumerable = preString.Select( c => Char.IsUpper(c) ? " " + c.ToString(): c.ToString()); MessageBox.Show(string.Concat(enumerable.ToArray())); IEnumerable<char> selectMany = preString.SelectMany(o => Char.IsUpper(o) ? o.ToString() : " " + o.ToString()); MessageBox.Show(new string(selectMany.ToArray()));

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
String preString = "HelloWorld";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in preString)
{
    if (Char.IsUpper(C))
        sb.Append(' ');
    sb.Append(C);
}

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: might want to then do a Split to get it into an array?

Comment: Yes, just split by white space...

Comment: @nofortee Remove the first space you've added and change the iteration variable to lower case c

Comment: @Jani: thanks for the reminding. I think the above code just give the clues about how to do that. Of course there's a little modification need to be done to fixed one's need. Thanks indeed.

Comment: Umm....Glad to hear that, cheers!!