# Batch renaming files C#

Tags: c#

I have a unity project that i need to rename basically all my files in it to contain a - as a way of easily identifying what assetbundle i need to load it from.

I would need to insert a `-` at the end of the identifier so for example, `testtest.png` would become `test-test.png` and so on.

I currently have this (just want to get the identifier from the file name itself for now) however, the first string in `temp` is always empty with the second one containing the rest of the file name

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
{
    string name = file.Split('\\').Last();
    if (name.StartsWith(args[0]))
    {
        string[] temp = name.Split(new[]{args[0]},StringSplitOptions.None);
        foreach (string s in temp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

```
D:\renamething\bin\Debug>renamething.exe test
.pdb
```

I tried `Regex` for it as well however it produced the same result, empty string in the first one, rest of it in the second.

Comment: what is args[0]

Comment: Arguments, its a console application. Should probs clarify that in the main post

Comment: Posted a code below, Please accept this as the answer if it works

Comment: `string name=file.Split('\\').Last();` <-- Don't do this. Use `Path` and `FileInfo` instead.

Comment: completely forgot about FileInfo, would've been nice if i remembered that earlier. ty

Comment: Why aren't you just using [a renamer program](https://github.com/sampctech/ab_renamer) (linked is my personal favorite) and doing something like a "find `test.`, replace `-test.`"

Comment: Wanted to try to figure it out myself, not use a already existing program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that would work, especially the args[0]

Try this:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))
    {
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file); //Get FileInfo

        if (!fileInfo.Name.StartsWith(args[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //If File doesn't start with the specified arguments, don't process
        {
            continue;
        }

        //Consider file -> C:/TestFolder/test.png
        var directory = fileInfo.DirectoryName;//Gives C:\TestFolder\
        var extension = fileInfo.Extension; //gives ".png"
        var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileInfo.Name); //Gives "test"

        var modifiedFileName = $"{fileName}-test{extension}"; //Gives "test-test.png

        var modifiedFullPath = $"{directory}/{modifiedFileName}";// C:\TestFolder\test-test.png

        fileInfo.MoveTo(modifiedFullPath);
    }
```

Comment: `!file.StartsWith(args)` <-- This won't work because `file` will contain the absolute path to the file, including `C:\etc\etc` part. Use `FileInfo.Name` instead.

Comment: Also, `StartsWith` is case-sensitive but Windows/NTFS is case-insensitive, so what you also _really_ need `fileInfo.Name.StartsWith( prefix, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )`.

Comment: `var extension = fileInfo.Extension; //gives "test"` <-- This is also incorrect. The return value will be `.png` ([it includes the dot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension?view=net-6.0)).

Comment: isn't exactly whats needed, i have for example a file in the project called QueenTexture.png, i need to insert a - between Queen and Texture so it becomes Queen-Texture.png (not asking for you to write what i want for free tho). I'll base what i have from this. ty

Comment: @Silentstorm well, you got it most of it. You probably oould figure out the rest. you can split the names by Capital Letters from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/4489046/6048531

Answer (score 0):

With the code from @Zee (and @Dai from having a second look over), here is what i ended up in the odd chance that anyone else in the future comes here and needs it

```
public static void Main(string[] args){
            foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())){
                FileInfo fileInfo=new FileInfo(file);
                if(fileInfo.Name.StartsWith(args[0])&&fileInfo.Name.EndsWith(".png"){
                    string[]temp=Regex.Split(fileInfo.Name, @"(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])");
                    temp[0]+="-";
                    File.Move(fileInfo.FullName,String.Concat(temp));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).