# Space between lowercase and uppercase letters in a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase

I want to add a space between a lowercase and uppercase in one string. For example:

```
FruityLoops
FirstRepeat
```

Now I want to add a space between the lowercase and uppercase letters. I don't know how I should start in JavaScript. Something with substr or search? Can somebody can help me?

Comment: @close voter: How exactly is this a duplicate of an XSLT question?!

Answer (score 22):

```
var str = "FruityLoops";

str = str.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3LYA8/

Comment: @Matt: It's better to have been up-voted and lost, than to have never been up-voted at all. :o)

Comment: @Frank, @patrick: Note that this will not add spaces between adjacent capitals, e.g. "FruityXLoops" => "Fruity XLoops", not "Fruity X Loops". Whether that's a feature or a bug is down to you, Frank. :-)

Comment: @patrick: hey now, I re-upvoted when you corrected the bug in your answer.

Comment: @Matt: Yes I saw that you re-up-voted. It was a poor transfer between a console version and a jsFiddle version. My console version worked, but was looser, then somewhere in the mix I only grabbed part of the revision. I figured that's why you removed it at first, and appropriate it was. Yoda?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Feature. *Always* a feature. ;o) Actually OP does state *"a space between the lowercase and uppercase"*.

Answer (score 3):

something simple like that :

```
"LoL".replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2")
```

is maybe sufficient ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a manual search, but it may be easier with a regex. Assuming:

- You know it starts with a capital
- You don't want a space in front of that capital
- You want a space in front of *all* subsequent capitals

Then:

```
function spacey(str) {  
    return str.substring(0, 1) +
           str.substring(1).replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(ch) {
        return " " + ch;
    });
}

alert(spacey("FruitLoops")); // "Fruit Loops"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uweco4)

More efficient version inspired by (but different from) [patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819829/space-between-lowercase-and-uppercase-letters-in-a-string-in-javascript/4819852#4819852):

```
function spacey(str) {  
    return str.substring(0, 1) +
           str.substring(1).replace(/([a-z])?([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
}

alert(spacey("FruityLoops"));  // "Fruity Loops"
alert(spacey("FruityXLoops")); // "Fruity X Loops"
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/uweco4/2)

Comment: Only solution I could find that deals with adjacent capital letters!! +1, good sir.

Comment: What does this mean - /([a-z])?([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2" ??? Look for small words that have small case letter followed by big. The small is optional. Put a space between the first group (small letter) and second group (capital)?

Comment: @stack1: Not words, characters. Other than that, yes, spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

The regexp option looks the best. Getting the regexp right appears to be tricky though.

There's another question here with some more complex options to try:

[Regular expression, split string by capital letter but ignore TLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097901/regular-expression-split-string-by-capital-letter-but-ignore-tla)

Comment: Most of that thread you link to is specific to C#, and won't work in JavaScript.