# Looking for regex to split on the string on upper case basis

Tags: c#, regex

Looking for regex  solution for following scenaio:

I have strings, which i have to split on the upper case basis but consecutive uppercase parts should not get split.

For example  : if the input is

```
DisclosureOfComparativeInformation
```

O/p should be

```
Disclosure Of Comparative Information
```

But consecutive uppercase should not get split.

`GAAP` should not result in `G A A P`.

How to find the particular pattern and insert space?

Thanx

Comment: Do you want to split the word only when there is one lower case and one upper case character ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try -

```
var subjectString = "DisclosureOfComparativeInformation";
var resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
[a-z](?=[A-Z])
```

With this call to replace:

```
regex.Replace(toMatch, "$& ")
```

For more information on the special replacement symbol "$&", see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx#EntireMatch

Answer (score 1):

`[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+`

will split as follows if replaced with match + space

`DisclosureOfComparativeInformation -> Disclosure Of Comparative Information`

`GAPS -> GAPS`

`SOmething -> SOmething` This one may be undesirable

`alllower -> alllower`

Answer (score 1):

```
((?<=[a-z])[A-Z]|[A-Z](?=[a-z]))
```

replace with

```
" $1"
```

In a second step you'd have to trim the string.

check out this link also......

[Regular expression, split string by capital letter but ignore TLA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097901/regular-expression-split-string-by-capital-letter-but-ignore-tla)

Answer (score 0):

Using regex solutions to look for strings where something is *not* true tends to become unrecognizable. I'd recommend you go through your string in a loop and split it accordingly without using regexp.

Answer (score 0):

In Perl this should work:

```
str =~ s/([A-Z][a-z])/ \1/g;
```

The parenthesis around the two character sets save the match for the "\1" (number one) later.

Comment: wont this only match the first two chars?

Comment: @smitec Thanks for catching that.  I have added the 'g' modifier to the end which replaces all occurrences of the pattern (in Perl).  Also, this solution would need to be trimmed, as in sikender's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split and Join:

```
string.Join(" ", Regex.Split("DisclosureOfComparativeInformation", @"([A-Z][a-z]*)"))
```